How to Add SVG Copy Icon with Clipboard Functionality in SharePoint Modern Pages?
I would like to trigger a copyToClipboard function when the user clicks on the SVG icon next to the email or phone numbers. However, I'm aware that SharePoint Online modern pages have restrictions on using inline JavaScript.
How can I implement this functionality while complying with SharePoint's restrictions? Do I need to use SPFx for this, or is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?
Any suggestions or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
